# Is there a library to do `setTimeout` in lua?

Tags: timer, lua, dependencies

I tried to use RxLua's [`TimeoutScheduler`](https://github.com/bjornbytes/RxLua/blob/master/src/schedulers/timeoutscheduler.lua#L22) to schedule a task.  But this results in lua complaining that there's no such module.

```
-- minimalexample.lua
scheduler = require('rx').TimeoutScheduler.create()
scheduler:schedule(function() return, 1000)
```

result:

```
lua: ./rx.lua:1913: module 'timer' not found:
...
stack traceback:
  [C]: in function 'require'
  ./rx.lua:1913: in method 'schedule'
  timedtest.lua:7: in main chunk
  [C]: in ?
```

I searched the webs to no avail.  Posted [an issue](https://github.com/bjornbytes/RxLua/issues/29) on the project page for it, too.

What module was needed there?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve] so we can see the issue you're facing ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `wait` or `sleep` function does not exist in standard Lua. [Luvit](http://luvit.io/), however, has a [timer](https://github.com/luvit/luvit/blob/master/deps/timer.lua) module that you can use to achieve the same functionality.

`local timer = require('timer')`

`timer.setTimeout(delay, callback, ...)` -- execute a callback once after a certain delay in milliseconds. varargs are passed to the callback on execution.

Answer (score 0):

The maintainer of the `RxLua` module was quite responsive to this:

https://github.com/bjornbytes/RxLua/issues/29#issuecomment-420311383

It depends on `luvit/timer`.